# create iterator in mongo php?

Tags: php, mongodb

i have this contact collection in mongo db. I need to create and return an iterator in php for this contact collection based on the company id.

```
function contact_iterator($company_id) 
{

   // code
}
```

how to create and return the iterator for contact collection based on the the company_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default result of a `find()` is a [MongoCursor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php) .. aka an iterator :).

```
<?php
    // Connect to MongoDB server
    $mongo = new Mongo();

    // Use database 'mydb' and collection 'contacts'
    $collection = $mongo->mydb->contacts;

    $cursor = $collection->find(array('company_id' => $company_id));

    // $company = $cursor->getNext();

    //  .. or .. 

    // foreach ($cursor as $company) {
        // ..
    // }
?>
```

Comment: How to insert the values of an array(got in php) in the mongodb in the corresponding fields?

Comment: @user1554472: it depends how you want to save them (as an array, as separate fields, as an embedded document, ..).  Best to start with a run through the [MongoDB PHP driver tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php).

Comment: pls.. help me with this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759330/how-to-insert-array-valuesphp-in-mongodb