# How to insert array values(php) in MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb

My contents of MongoDB(when i used find()) is like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("50072b17b4a6de3b11000001"),
  "addresses": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("50072b17b4a6de3b11000004"),
      "address1": "770 27th Ave",
      "address2": null,
      "city": "San Mateo",
      "country": "United States",
      "country_code": "US",
      "name": "home",
      "primary": true,
      "state": "California",
      "zip": "94403"
    }
  ],
  "biography": null,
  "category_ids": [],
  "department": null,
  "emails": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("50072b17b4a6de3b11000003"),
      "_type": "Email",
      "name": "work",
      "email": "alan@altimetergroup.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I need to do is I need to update this MongoDB with additional datas's. For that I need to get the values in php as an array and insert that array in to this collection. How to get the values for these specified fields as an array in php and how to insert those in php??

Comment: Are you trying to [insert new documents](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.insert.php) or [update and save](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.save.php) changes to one you've retrieved?  As suggested on one of your related questions, it would be worth taking the time to go through the [PHP MongoDB driver tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php) as it includes examples of all of the basics.

Comment: @Stennie  am trying to insert new documents. btw inserting an array is little easy. but when u see the example above when inserting the multi dimensional array, each inner array is having separate object id. which means each inner array is another object. how to insert such an array??

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = $this->collection->findOne(array('_id' => MONGO_ID));
//Update things
$this->collection->update(array('_id' => $array['_id']), $array);
```

MONGO_ID in my example should represent the '_id' MongoDB automatically assigns.  Make sure it is sent as an Object, and not as a string.

Comment: This is for updating existing data. How to do when i want to insert a new datas (i mean with new object id's) ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add another entry, you add an entry like so:

```
$this->collection->insert($array_of_data, array('safe' => true));
```

Answer (score 0):

For insert:

```
$id = new MongoId();
$test->insert(array('t' => 'test', 'email' => array('_id' => $id, 'email' => 'ccc@ccc.com')));
```

And the result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5088cba86527044a31000001"), "t" : "test", "email" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5088cba86527044a31000000"), "email" : "ccc@ccc.com" } }
```

It works :)